# What's the reason some of the Detective Neuro's manga cover's page are upside down?

Tags: neuro-supernatural-detective

I have 12 out of 23 volumes of [*Majin Tantei Nogami Neuro*](https://myanimelist.net/manga/674/Majin_Tantei_Nougami_Neuro). It's really weird since the first tenth volume of this manga's cover is upside down like you could see in this [site](https://comicvine.gamespot.com/majin-tantei-nogami-neuro/4050-44334/).

What's the reason behind it?

Comment: Have a look at [this](http://easternstandard.pbworks.com/w/page/18183978/Majin%20Tantei%20Nougami%20Neuro)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**There's no particular reason other than "because the mangaka wanted it that way".**

It's just one of the many *omake*/additional fun things about the tankobon (according to [Japanese Wikipedia](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E9%AD%94%E4%BA%BA%E6%8E%A2%E5%81%B5%E8%84%B3%E5%99%9B%E3%83%8D%E3%82%A6%E3%83%AD#%E5%8D%98%E8%A1%8C%E6%9C%AC%E6%81%92%E4%BE%8B%E3%81%AE%E3%81%8A%E3%81%BE%E3%81%91)):

- The characters on the cover page are upside-down on vol. 1-10, as-is on vol. 11-20, and left-turned on vol. 21-22(23)

Some other trivia:

- The name of the criminal of that volume

  > is hidden in the background of wall-of-text in the table of contents (except vol. 15, 16, and 23), e.g. [vol. 11's criminal name](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f69tp.png). ([Source](http://nyuge3.cocolog-nifty.com/nyuge/2007/05/post.html))
- The illustration on the middle cover of vol. 10-19

  > uses "Hanging Yako" representing "1", e.g. [vol. 18](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i5hJ1.jpg). ([Source](http://hespaus.blog41.fc2.com/blog-entry-451.html))
- The cover pages for vol. 13-20

  > are connected: [13-16](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yYEGG.png) and [17-20](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g3RAX.png). ([Source](http://manga.zoku-sei.com/%E9%AD%94%E4%BA%BA%E6%8E%A2%E5%81%B5%E3%80%80%E8%84%B3%E5%99%9B%E3%83%8D%E3%82%A6%E3%83%AD/%E9%AD%94%E4%BA%BA%E6%8E%A2%E5%81%B5%E8%84%B3%E5%99%9B%E3%83%8D%E3%82%A6%E3%83%AD%E3%81%AE%E3%81%A4%E3%81%AA%E3%81%8C%E3%82%8B%E8%A1%A8%E7%B4%99%E9%9B%86))